# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by - wp-includes\script-loader.php:2011) in

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a custom function for Export table data to to Excel sheets in WordPress plugin  .

My function :-

```html
   public function csv_download(){
        $header_row = array(
            0 => 'Sr.No',
            1 => 'name',
            2 => 'email',
            3 => 'Registration Date',
        );
        $data_rows = array();
        global $wpdb, $bp;
        $users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, user_email, user_registered FROM {$wpdb->users} WHERE user_status = 0" );
        foreach ( $users as $u ) {
            $row = array();
            $row[0] =  $u->ID ;
            $row[1] = $u->user_name;
            $row[2] = $u->user_email;
            $row[3] = $u->user_registered;
            $data_rows[] = $row;
        }
        $fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
        //fprintf( $fh, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) );
        header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
        header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
        header( 'Content-type: text/csv' );
        header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.csv\";" );
        header( 'Expires: 0' );
        header( 'Pragma: public' );
        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        fputcsv( $fh, $header_row );
        foreach ( $data_rows as $data_row ) {
            fputcsv( $fh, $data_row );
        }
        fclose( $fh );
        die();
        
    }
```

But I keep getting an error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already solved the issue but maybe my answer will help someone else.

You should attach your actions to some early hook when no headers are yet sent, For instance the `admin_init` hook.

So:

1. `add_action('admin_init', 'your_custom_function');
2. In `your_custom_function` you should probably verify the `$_GET` variables to check if user clicked your link or something totally different
3. If that was your link you should with no issues echo the headers and the contents of your data to download.